# Can anyone tell where i am doing it wrong, "sending the data from fragment to fragment"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm sending data between fragments but i get null bundle.

i am sending data from one fragment to another fragment in a recycle view by click the button call, the information will be send to call logs through bundles. the buttons are set on adapter. this is my first question here i can do a mistake, apologies if any.

Communication interface:

```
public interface FragmentCommunication{

    void response(int position, String name, String designation);

}
```

This is FRAGMENT 1:

```
public class fragmentHome extends Fragment 

{

    private View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<contacts> contact = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        HomeAdaptor recycler = new HomeAdaptor(getContext(),contact,communication);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycler);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contact.add(new contacts("Mehfooz","Android Developer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Zabhi","IOS developer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Ali","java coder"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Ahmed","testerr"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Aqib","Designer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("fahad","Project manager"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Mehfooz","Android Developer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Zabhi","IOS developer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Ali","java coder"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Ahmed","testerr"));
        contact.add(new contacts("Aqib","Designer"));
        contact.add(new contacts("fahad","Project manager"));
    }
    FragmentCommunication communication = new FragmentCommunication() {
        @Override
        public void response(int position, String name, String designation) {
            FragmentCall fragmentCall = new FragmentCall();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name" , name);
            bundle.putString("designation", designation);
            fragmentCall.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    };
}
```

This is the Fragment 1 Adapter viewholder listener Code:

```
    //making a phone call dialog is showing...
    makecall = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    makecall.setContentView(R.layout.make_a_call);
    viewHolder.callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageButton endbutton = (ImageButton) makecall.findViewById(R.id.imageCallEndButton);
            TextView callName = (TextView) makecall.findViewById(R.id.makeCallTextName);
            TextView callDesignation =(TextView) makecall.findViewById(R.id.makeCallTextDesignation);
            callName.setText(data.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
            callDesignation.setText(data.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDesignation());
            Toast.makeText(context,"Calling...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            makecall.show();
            //CallEnd button listener
            endbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    makecall.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"END CALL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    communication.response(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),
                            data.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName(),
                            data.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDesignation());
                }
            });
            viewHolder.chatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    holder.designation.setText(data.get(position).getDesignation());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", data.get(position).getName());
    bundle.putString("designation", data.get(position).getDesignation());
    fragmentCall.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

This is the Fragment 2:

```
public class FragmentCall extends Fragment{

    private View view;
    private List<callLog> callLog = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    String designation;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_call, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.callList);
        CallAdaptor recycler = new CallAdaptor(getContext(),callLog);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycler);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            name = bundle.getString("name");
            designation = bundle.getString("designation");
            callLog.add(new callLog(name,designation));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "name" + name + "designation" + designation , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "bundle is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

i dont get error except the null data im getting from the bundles.
if anyone can help me with this... thank you!!

Comment: You're not showing enough code

Comment: do i have to add more?? i thought it would be enough. what else i have to past. there is fragment 2 adapter class. and xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the bind view and click listener to your `onBindViewHolder` instead of `onCreateViewHolder`. Then get the adapter item by the position only once.

You must not create a bundle inside `onBindViewHolder` because it will be called multiple times and make your application dirty with unused object. So, you should not use this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    holder.designation.setText(data.get(position).getDesignation());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", data.get(position).getName());
    bundle.putString("designation", data.get(position).getDesignation());
    fragmentCall.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Use something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // don't call this multiple times especially inside anonymous method
    // because the index position can be different from the previous call.
    int itemPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    callLog datum = data.get(itemPosition);

    holder.name.setText(datum.getName());
    holder.designation.setText(datum.getDesignation());

    ...

    holder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
            communication.response(itemPosition, itemPosition.getName(),
                    itemPosition.getDesignation());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What you are missing here is these lines of code.Your are not adding new fragment on the same framelayout.

You have to add these lines as well after setting bundle in argument:
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_view, fragmentCall);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

//replace or add what ever you want

Comment: hello sir, thank you for answering my query. may i know where should i put these lines in my code.

Comment: inside this method 
FragmentCommunication communication = new FragmentCommunication() {
        @Override
        public void response(int position, String name, String designation) {
            FragmentCall fragmentCall = new FragmentCall();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name" , name);
            bundle.putString("designation", designation);
            fragmentCall.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    };

Comment: hi, that really works sends data to call fragment and store data properly there, but it still show "null" when i click on bottom navigation button.

Comment: it is simple as like we are dailing a call and data sended to call log..

Comment: This is may be because you are sending data on item click or recylerview item when you are clicking on bottom navigation menus bundle is going with fragment with empty data. Put some your own logic there as well because I don't have your complete code. I just answering your question to send data from item click of recylerview